# Create column on execute time in TcxGrid like tDbGrid in delphi

Tags: delphi, tcxgrid

I use TcxGrid But I cant create fields on execution time
because I have a pivot query and columns are variable

Can I fill cxGrid like tDbGrid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem like this

```
grdCevapDBTableView2.BeginUpdate;
grdCevapDBTableView2.ClearItems;
fillGridView(grdCevapDBTableView2,command);
grdCevapDBTableView2.DataController.CreateAllItems;
grdCevapDBTableView2.EndUpdate;
```

Comment: Hey, can I ask where you get the fillGridView function from? I have the same problem, but this doesn't compile for me.

Comment: Sorry I just saw your comment. it was a user defined function. so many years passed I forgot its form. but it was in a class and working with that two parameters.

Comment: Thanks for our answer. I think I solved my problem last year though.

Comment: actually clearItems and createallitems would have been enough.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use the TcxGrid.DataController.CreateAllItems method which creates all columns that exists in the datasource. It takes a boolean parameter with which you can decide wether to add all columns or only those missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function TForm1.AddIntegerColumn(const ACaption, AName: string): TcxGridColumn;
begin
  Result := TableView.CreateColumn;
  Result.DataBinding.ValueTypeClass := TcxIntegerValueType;
  Result.Caption := ACaption;
  Result.Name := AName;
end;
```